# What do you call a web layout style where a single scrollbar moves all content until each one hits bottom?

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, scrolling, facebook

This style is being used more and more, but cannot figure out a proper term to call it.

Constraints:
Universal scrollbar, user can scroll from any mouse location in the viewport with the same effect.
Each section scrolls in parallel until a section runs out of content, it pins to the bottom of the screen.
Scrolling back up, each section's content starts scrolling once the longest page has reached the length of the section content.

Most visible in Facebook with its right-hand notifications and infinite scrolling content.  A similar effect is visible on this very StackExchange "ask" page when entering a question: the suggestions scroll until out of space then stay static, the main content continues to scroll.

Answer (score 5):

Those are **floating** (side) **navigation**. I have used [sticky float jquery plugin](http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html) in the past to implement it.

Comment: That's a good general term.  We've since come to call it "pinned" sidebars to clarify that the referred content may still scroll with the page in some cases.  The Scrollerama [http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/] website examples are helpful for visualizing.